# Find an integral of differential form taken on $M^2$ manifold by Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds, differential-forms

Given manifold $$M^2 = \bigl\{(x, y, z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4, x \leq z \bigr\}$$ and normal $$n_x(-1, 0, 0) > 0.$$ 
I'm trying to find next integral of diff form: $\iint_{M^2}x^2\,dy \wedge dz + \cos x\, dx \wedge dz$ using Stokes' theorem.
According to the theorem: $$d(x^2\,dy \wedge dz + \cos x\: dx \wedge dz = 2x \:dx\wedge dy \wedge dz) + 0.$$
By our constraints we have half of a sphere. In the normal coordinates х coord doesn't equal to z coord - thus, our dot is in our half-sphere.
I took this parameterization for the sphere: $$(x, y, z) = (r \sin (u) \sin (v), r \cos (u), r \sin (u) \cos (v))$$
Since I need to calculate the normal for the point of the sphere, I've fixed the radius $r = 2$ and searched the normal to a circle, I suppose (I have doubts here). Found vector, orthogonal to two vectors, which sets the circle parametrization. So it's required vector.
We substitute the coordinates into it from the condition and look at the fulfillment of the condition that at a given point it's positive. Since it's not running I need to find either new parametrization, or simply take "-" sign before the integral.
I took second path with "-".
Further, from the result obtained by Stokes' theorem and the normal, we obtain that unknown integral is equal to the integral
$$-\iiint_{M^3} 2x _,dx\wedge dy\wedge dz.$$ Here it turns out, I also need to subtract the integral $$\iint_{\partial^+M^3}... ,$$ though I'm not sure about that.
The value of a triple integral is $4\sqrt{2} \pi.$
Tell me, please, am I doing everything right, and is it necessary to subtract this integral? And what generally happens then under the sign of this integral, because there is $\cos (x)$ from given conditions?

Comment: Stokes theorem requires the whole, closed boundary of the triple integral region, which your original $2$-manifold was not.

Comment: A quick way to see this is that if it were a boundary, it would satisfy the condition that all boundaries have $\partial(\partial M) = \{0\}$. But the boundary of the first manifold is a circle.

Comment: So because of this i've written part with substracting integral taken on the board of M^3. Eiter i can't understand you. If i add this board artifically, will i can to use Stokes theorem?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, could you rephrase please?

Comment: Sure. I want to use Stokes theorem - it is required for me. SO. I need whole and closed boundary, which i don't have. If i will add this board(i mean i don't know some integral, or change one of conditions) and get my good boundary, can i use Stokes theorem?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: ok, fine. But problem is, that i don't know what am i need to add). Can you tell me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102558/discussion-between-juicer-and-ninad-munshi).